# How to create Dynamically Jquery Datatatable with Headers in MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a Monthly report in MVC. For that I need to create the days of user selected month as it's heading. But When I try to set it by sing the jquery It show some errors.

> Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '61764' in [{"Name":"Abel John","Father Name":John,"Sex":"Male","Date of Birth ....

I'm new to Jquery and MVC . here Is my code . Please help me to solve the issue.

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetLeaveDeatais", "LeaveDetails")?year=' + date,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            year: { year: '2013' },
            contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',

            success: function () {



                }
        })
            .success(function (result) {
                $('#divDetails').html(function () {

                    var cols = [];

                   var dataSet = result;

                    var my_columns = [];

                    $.each(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dataSet)), function (key, value) {
                        var my_item = {};
                        my_item.data = key;
                        my_item.title = key;

                        my_columns.push(my_item); 
                    });
                    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
                        columns: my_columns

                    });

                }

                );
        });
```

My Controler

```
 public  string GetLeaveDeatais(string year)
    {

        List<DataRow> list = new List<DataRow>();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        MusterRoll mstRoll= new MusterRoll();

        dt = clsBD.GetEmpLeaveDeatils("2019-05-1");

            if (dt != null)
            list=dt.AsEnumerable().ToList();
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();


        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> row;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
            }
            rows.Add(row);
        }

        return serializer.Serialize(rows);

    }
```

Please find me to get a solution soon.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: *It show some errors* ... what errors does it show? Please add the errors/exceptions to your question

Comment: could you post the (sample) json string that your controller returns.

Comment: @CuriousBee could you post the (sample) json string that your controller returns. Also, which line exactly showing that error? From error, to me, it seems like something is wrong with .each loop.

Comment: @sam sorry I can't It showing text limit error in SO

Comment: @CuriousBee  Please update your post so others will get context of that error message.